# Live SASS Compiler creating extra files?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, npm, sass, vscode-extensions

I'm currently trying to learn how to implement SASS into my web development projects but I'm struggling a little bit with figuring out how to properly compile my `.scss` files into one single `.css` file.

When I run `sass --version` in my terminal, I receive `1.53.0 compiled with dart2js 2.17.3`. As far as extensions go, I'm using Live Sass Compiler by Glenn Marks, and within the `settings.json` file, my configuration looks like this:

```
{
  "liveSassCompile.settings.formats":[
     {
         "format": "expanded",
         "extensionName": ".css",
         "savePath": "/css"
     },
 ],
 "liveSassCompile.settings.excludeList": [
    "**/node_modules/**",
    ".vscode/**"
 ],
 "liveSassCompile.settings.generateMap": true,
 "liveSassCompile.settings.autoprefix": [
     "defaults"
 ]
}
```

This is my current project directory:
[Current Project Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlAkZ.png)

My current issue is that whenever I click `Watch Sass`, the only file I want to be output is the `main.css` and `main.css.map` but it creates an `index.css` and `index.css.map` file as well.

I'm trying to implement something similar to the *7 - 1 SASS Architecture*, and within each of those folders I created an `index.scss` that'll contain each file in it's directory, which will then be `@forward` to the `main.scss`.

Is there any particular way I can avoid the extra files being created? I'm not too familiar with `npm` but I've heard it would be more beneficial to learn it in order to utilize SASS as opposed to using a VS Code extension and I'm more than open to taking that approach and scrapping the entire extension as a whole if it proves to be more efficient.

Thank you for your help in advanced, I hope I provided enough information!

Answer (score 1):

Dart sass comes with an inbuilt compiler
Just run the code

sass --watch sass/main.scss css/main.css

Comment: Guess what, this also adds the .css.map file lol

Comment: Thank you so much, I had no idea I could run such a simple command in the terminal to save me so much time. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

If you decide to stick with my extension then you can specify a single file to output/watch with the [`liveSassCompile.settings.includeItems`](https://github.com/glenn2223/vscode-live-sass-compiler/blob/master/docs/settings.md#livesasscompilesettingsincludeitems) setting - as shown below

```js
{
    "liveSassCompile.settings.includeItems": [ "/path/to/main.scss" ]
}
```

Alternatively, and possibly a better solution, you can use a negative glob expression in the [`liveSassCompile.settings.partialsList`](https://github.com/glenn2223/vscode-live-sass-compiler/blob/master/docs/settings.md#livesasscompilesettingspartialslist) to treat every other file as a partial. Then, when any SASS file is saved, it triggers compilation of just your `main.scss` file

An example of this would be `**/!(main).scss`. It's the `!()` that is the negative glob pattern, it means if the pattern inside matches then ignore it.

You can see it action over at https://globster.xyz/. Just use the setup below

- paste the glob pattern above in to the main field
- Click edit files and paste the below into the field

```
/myapp/main.scss
/myapp/partials/file1.scss
/myapp/other.scss
```

- click apply and it should be updated and everything but the main file should be blue

Comment: This "negative glob" suggestion sounds like what I'm looking for -- can you elaborate? I watched your video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Wo3mYBLNyA but it really didn't cover globs in detail

Comment: I have expanded my answer now to include a negative glob pattern example. There a lot to glob patterns so, if you wanted to know more, there's a little info at the link I provided, but more if you search online. Would you find it useful to have me do a video on glob patterns?

Comment: Hi Glenn, I definitely would find a video on glob patterns useful.

Answer (score 0):

This one faulty line is probably the reason for your problem.
Change this:

```json
 "liveSassCompile.settings.generateMap": true,
```

to this:

```json
 "liveSassCompile.settings.generateMap": false,
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It worked but I've decided to drop the extension primarily because I recently learned it is a little more convenient to use `sass --watch sass/main.scss css/main.css`